# What are the real world applications involving Laplace transforms?

Tags: fourier-transform, laplace-transform

Laplace transform is really interesting. Speaking about Fourier transform, there are many real world applications like we use in removal of noise and Laplace transform is again the extension of Fourier transform. Can anyone clearly explain the real world applications which mainly rely on Laplace transform and how it could be implemented in briefly?

Comment: I don't understand this question at all.  Laplace transform and Fourier transform are mathematical tools that can be used to model and understand some systems. It's not clear what an "application" would be in the sense that you're using it in your question.

Comment: I get your point @Brick. The real world applications of Fourier transform being said Digital signal processing, system modelling and noise removal, and so on. Having said with Laplace transform is just the Fourier transform of waded function(modified function). How really is it used in real world applications in differing to Fourier transform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laplace transforms are extensively used in mechanical engineering, in the specialties known as *dynamic systems modeling and analysis* and *control system design*. In both these fields, the differential equations that describe the behavior of complex systems are converted into their equivalent *s-forms*, solved in that domain, and then converted back.